# Video trimming on Android using MediaCodec, Media Extractor and Media Muxer

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

In my Android App I need a solution when the user can trim a video from internal storage. I am trying to achieve this without using any third-party library. I was referencing this Google's Gallery App source code  [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/634248d/src/com/android/gallery3d/app/VideoUtils.java). But I am getting the following error :

timestampUs 66733 < lastTimestampUs 133467 for Video track

There are few SO questions which talk about this timestamp issue, but I am really not being to figure out as I am new to using MediaCodecs, MediaMuxers etc. Would be great if any can hep

Here's my code :

```
 // Set up MediaExtractor to read from the source.
    MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
    extractor.setDataSource(srcPath);
    int trackCount = extractor.getTrackCount();
    System.out.println("tracl" + trackCount);
    // Set up MediaMuxer for the destination.
    MediaMuxer muxer;
    muxer = new MediaMuxer(dstPath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);



    // Set up the tracks and retrieve the max buffer size for selected
    // tracks.
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<>(trackCount);
    int bufferSize = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < trackCount; i++) {
        MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);


        String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
        boolean selectCurrentTrack = false;
        if (mime.startsWith("audio/") && useAudio) {
            selectCurrentTrack = true;
        } else if (mime.startsWith("video/") && useVideo) {
            selectCurrentTrack = true;
        }
        if (selectCurrentTrack) {
            extractor.selectTrack(i);
            int dstIndex = muxer.addTrack(format);
            System.out.println(format);
            System.out.println("dstIndex" + dstIndex);

            indexMap.put(i, dstIndex);
            if (format.containsKey(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE)) {
                int newSize = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE);
                bufferSize = newSize > bufferSize ? newSize : bufferSize;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(indexMap);

    if (bufferSize < 0) {
        bufferSize = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
    }
    // Set up the orientation and starting time for extractor.
    MediaMetadataRetriever retrieverSrc = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retrieverSrc.setDataSource(srcPath);
    String degreesString = retrieverSrc.extractMetadata(
            MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION);
    if (degreesString != null) {
        int degrees = Integer.parseInt(degreesString);
        if (degrees >= 0) {
            muxer.setOrientationHint(degrees);
        }
    }
    if (startMs > 0) {
        extractor.seekTo(startMs * 1000, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
    }


  //  System.out.println(extractor.);
    // Copy the samples from MediaExtractor to MediaMuxer. We will loop
    // for copying each sample and stop when we get to the end of the source
    // file or exceed the end time of the trimming.
    int offset = 0;
    int trackIndex = -1;
    ByteBuffer dstBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();


    try {
        muxer.start();
        while (true) {

            System.out.println("copying");
            bufferInfo.offset = offset;


            bufferInfo.size = extractor.readSampleData(dstBuf, offset);



            if (bufferInfo.size < 0 ) {
               // InstabugSDKLogger.d(TAG, "Saw input EOS.");
                System.out.println("Saw input EOS.");
                bufferInfo.size = 0;
                break;
            } else {

                /**
                 * The presentation timestamp in microseconds for the buffer.
                 * This is derived from the presentation timestamp passed in
                 * with the corresponding input buffer.  This should be ignored for
                 * a 0-sized buffer.
                 */

                /**
                 * Returns the current sample's presentation time in microseconds.
                 * or -1 if no more samples are available.
                 */
                bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = extractor.getSampleTime();

                //1 sec = 1000000 micco sec


                if (endMs > 0 && bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs > (endMs * 1000)) {


                    break;
                } else {
                    bufferInfo.flags = extractor.getSampleFlags();
                    trackIndex = extractor.getSampleTrackIndex();


                    muxer.writeSampleData(indexMap.get(trackIndex), dstBuf, bufferInfo);

                    //System.out.println(muxer);
                    extractor.advance();
                }
            }
        }

        muxer.stop();




        File file = new File(srcPath);
        file.delete();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {



        System.out.println("The source video file is malformed");


    } finally {


        muxer.release();

    }
```

Comment: This could be a lot of things, but my first thought, seeing the timestamps, was that 2 of your first 3 video samples are out-of-order (in terms of the presentation time). This is normal for some formats, e.g., "H.264 main". Instead, these samples are ordered by composition time. Since `MediaExtractor/Muxer` don't seem to support composition times, that leads me to believe that you're stuck with simpler formats, e.g., "H.264 baseline". If you want to prove my theory, just write a routine to dump all the input presentation times, and see if they're strictly ordered or not.

Comment: hey @greeble31 just checked. The presentation times are not ordered. And it is crashing when the order breaks

Comment: By the way, what version of android are you testing on? MediaMuxer only supports B-frames after Nougat.

Comment: Hello Sir, the android version is 6

Comment: Your video have B-frames in it which means pts may not be monotonically increasing which is only supported since andoid Nougat. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer. You have 3 options, use android 7 or above, only use baseline profile video, or reencode the video using mediacodec with baseline profile before muxing